# sharing video page on facebook like youtube video page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

i have a video page which i want to share on facebook. once i share that page on the facebook its showing video which can be played on the facebook itself. i want that video page should be shown as youtube page shared on facebook with the video on left side and title description on right side. once you click on the video it will expand and starts playing(copy any video link from the youtube and share you will see the video on left title description on the rightside)

as in the following image

[image]

following og tags i have added

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Tilt Viral App" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://tilt.regalixdigital.com/share.php?id=video1503325335" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Test11" />

<meta property="og:video:url" content="https://tilt.regalixdigital.com/tilt_videos/video1503325335.mp4" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="text/html" />
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://tilt.regalixdigital.com/tilt_videos/video1503325335.mp4" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="600" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="400" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Tilt" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://tilt.regalixdigital.com/images/new-design/FB_Poster.jpg" />
```

my video page 
https://tilt.regalixdigital.com/share.php?id=video1503325335

Comment: any help will be very usefull.

Comment: Try a square image instead. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images

Comment: Thanks CBroe. struggle lot for this never new just resizing the image will solve this thanks lot